# Jquery Datepicker CSS is not working inside modal

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, datepicker

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.2 with Visual Form Builder Plugin, when I'm using Jquery Datepicker in a regular page, it works correctly.

But If I'm using Jquery Datepicker inside a Tab/Modal/dialog box, the CSS styling is gone missing. Please help. Pic here: 
[image]

Here's the Link: http://bit.ly/1uAWdqS (Book Test Drive Tab - Hari)

I don't understand what's wrong with it. Please help, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like you arn't including the css from jquery ui? This is required to style their elements. Since you are including bootstrap already why not try one of the various bootstrap datepickers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this css file to yout header.php:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```